# I used the below code to transform year to age using custom pipe using angular. But for some particular date of birth it is showing as NAN years

Tags: angular

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
@Pipe({
  name: 'age'
})
export class AgePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Date): string {
    let today = moment();
    let birthdate = moment(value);
    let years = today.diff(birthdate, 'years');
    let html:string = years + " yr ";
    return html;
  }
}
```

In the HTM, I have `{{personalInfo.birthDate| age}}` where `personalInfo` is a object.

Comment: Can you please share that particular date of birth where it is showing NaN?

Comment: 14/06/1984 . For this date of birth I am no getting the age

Comment: For some date it is showing age for some other date it is not showing age . Example 14/06/1984 and other dates it is not showing the age

Comment: This code part is correct, but date format coming from backend was different due to that, it was not giving proper age.. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to make sure you're passing a correct date to the pipe.

By using the Moment library, you can check if the date is valid by:

```
const birthdate = moment(value)
if(birthdate.isValid()){
 // your rest of code here
}
```

By knowing the above code, I would recommend changing your code to:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
@Pipe({
  name: 'age'
})
export class AgePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Date): string {
    const birthdate = moment(value);
    if(birthdate.valid()){
      const today = moment();
      const years = today.diff(birthdate, 'years');
      return years + " yr ";
    }
  }
}
```